# Can many threads set bit on the same word simultaneously?

Tags: cuda

I need each thread of a warp deciding on setting or not its respective bit in a 32 bits word.  Does this multiple setting take only one memory access, or will be one memory access for each bit set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no independent bit-setting capability in CUDA.  (There is a [bit-field-insert](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#integer-arithmetic-instructions-bfi) instruction in PTX, but it nevertheless operates on a 32-bit quantity.)

Each thread would set a bit by doing a full 32-bit write.  Such a write would need to be an atomic RMW operation in order to preserve the other bits.  Therefore the accesses would effectively be serialized, at whatever the throughput of atomics are.

If memory space is not a concern, breaking the bits out into separate integers would allow you to avoid atomics.

A 32-bit packed quantity could then be quickly assembled using the `__ballot()` [warp vote function](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#warp-vote-functions).  An example is given in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26206544/parallel-radix-sort-how-would-this-implementation-actually-work-are-there-some/26229897#26229897).

(In fact, the warp vote function may allow you to avoid memory transactions altogether; everything can be handled in registers, if the only result you need is the 32-bit packed quantity.)

Comment: ballot, that's exactly what I needed!