# Why this Radix-sort CUDA code sorts only 32 elements?

Tags: visual-studio, sorting, cuda, gpu, radix-sort

When I execute this code in Visual Studio 15 it only sorts 32 elements. If I set WSIZE greater than 32 or less than 32, it shows the same unsorted elements as output. Can anyone please help me?

**My system info.**

Processor - Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz, 2400 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)

RAM - 8GB

Dedicated graphics - NVIDIA GeForce 940M 4GB (384 CUDA Cores)

This is the output for WSIZE set to 32 https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjgZI.jpg

This is the output for WSIZE set to 19 https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXiG5.jpg

This is the output for WSIZE set to 50 https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rPYo.jpg

```
#pragma once
#ifdef __INTELLISENSE__
void __syncthreads();
#endif

#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

#define WSIZE 32 /*to set No. of elements to sort and also set No. of threads*/
#define LOOPS 2
#define UPPER_BIT 4
#define LOWER_BIT 0

__device__ unsigned int ddata[WSIZE];
__device__ int ddata_s[WSIZE];

__global__ void parallelRadix()
{
    // This data in shared memory
    __shared__ volatile unsigned int sdata[WSIZE];

    // Load from global into shared variable
    sdata[threadIdx.x] = ddata[threadIdx.x];

    unsigned int bitmask = 1;
    unsigned int offset = 0;
    // -1, -2, -4, -8, -16, -32, -64, -128, -256,...
    unsigned int thrmask = 0xFFFFFFFFU << threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int mypos;

    // For each LSB to MSB
    for (int i = LOWER_BIT; i < UPPER_BIT; i++)
    {
        unsigned int mydata = sdata[((WSIZE - 1) - threadIdx.x) + offset];
        unsigned int mybit = mydata&bitmask;
        // Get population of ones and zeroes
        unsigned int ones = __ballot(mybit);
        unsigned int zeroes = ~ones;
        // Switch ping-pong buffers
        offset ^= WSIZE;

        // Do zeroes, then ones
        if (!mybit)
        {
            mypos = __popc(zeroes&thrmask);
        }
        else {      // Threads with a one bit
                    // Get my position in ping-pong buffer
            mypos = __popc(zeroes) + __popc(ones&thrmask);
        }

        // Move to buffer  (or use shfl for cc 3.0)
        sdata[mypos - 1 + offset] = mydata;
        // Repeat for next bit
        bitmask <<= 1;
    }
    // Put results to global
    ddata[threadIdx.x] = sdata[threadIdx.x + offset];
}

int main() {

    /* Parallel Radix Sort */

    unsigned int hdata[WSIZE];
    float totalTime = 0;
    LARGE_INTEGER cicles;
    for (int lcount = 0; lcount < LOOPS; lcount++)
    {
        //srand(time(NULL));
        // Array elements have value in range of 1024
        unsigned int range = 1U << UPPER_BIT;

        // Fill array with random elements
        // Range = 1024
        //srand(time(0));
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&cicles);
        srand(cicles.QuadPart);
        printf("\n input array  %d\n", lcount);
        for (int i = 0; i < WSIZE; i++)
        {
            hdata[i] = rand() % range;
            printf("%u ", hdata[i]);

        }


        // Copy data from host to device
        cudaMemcpyToSymbol(ddata, hdata, WSIZE * sizeof(unsigned int));

        // Execution time measurement, that point starts the clock
        high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
        parallelRadix << < 1, WSIZE >> >();
        // Make kernel function synchronous
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        // Execution time measurement, that point stops the clock
        high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

        // Execution time measurement, that is the result
        auto duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count();

        // Summination of each loops' execution time
        totalTime += (float)duration / 1000.00;

        // Copy data from device to host
        cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(hdata, ddata, WSIZE * sizeof(unsigned int));

        printf("\n sorted array %d\n", lcount);
        for (int i = 0; i < WSIZE; i++)
            printf("%u ", hdata[i]);


    }
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Parallel Radix Sort:\n");
    printf("Array size = %d\n", WSIZE * LOOPS);
    printf("Time elapsed = %fseconds\n", totalTime);

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26206544/parallel-radix-sort-how-would-this-implementation-actually-work-are-there-some/26229897#26229897).  I wrote it.

It is only designed to sort 32 elements, because it was designed to work with only a single warp in CUDA, which is 32 threads. It was never designed or intended to sort more than 32 elements, and many of the tricks it uses at the warp level would have to be re-written to work at larger than warp scale.   `WSIZE` stands for WARP SIZE, and in CUDA the size of the warp is 32 threads.  You cannot change the warp size.

If you want to do a sort on a larger data set, use an operation from [thrust](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__sorting.html) or [cub](https://nvlabs.github.io/cub/structcub_1_1_device_radix_sort.html).

Comment: can you please guide me where can I find CUDA examples which uses thrust or cub operations? And is it possible to modify your CUDA code?

Comment: Thrust sorting example is [here](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/sort.cu).  CUB sort example is [here](https://nvlabs.github.io/cub/structcub_1_1_device_radix_sort.html), scroll down until you see "snippet"